# How can I get Volume GUIDs using WMI?

Tags: windows, wmi, usb

Is there any way to retrieve the following type of path:

\\?\Volume{GUID}\

for USB drives Using WMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows 2003 and above ( not XP !) you can use: [Win32_Volume Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(VS.85).aspx).

I don't think there is a way to retrieve the guid with wmi in xp and below. Can't be sure.

albert refers to the [GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959573) call. There is a sample in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch this Information from Sytem Registry. Reading System Registry (both local and Remote) is Possible through WMI using the StdRegProv provider.